# Why does many body localized phase follow Poisson distribution?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body

In many body localization (MBL) phenomenon, the ergodic phase follows a Gaussian distribution and MBL phase follows Poisson distribution.

I can understand the Gaussian distribution, as this follows from the symmetry of the system. But I can't understand why would MBL follow poisson distribition.
Because if it follows poisson distribution then it would mean that the positioning of energy level in spectrum is completely random i.e. it is probability of finding a level in an interval dE is same at every energy. Is there a physical argument to support this?

Answer (score 1):

The physical argument, based on random matrix theory, is that the off-diagonal elements of the Hamiltonian are suppressed at strong disorder. Therefore, two states close in energy are typically localized far apart in Fock space. This means that the states do not interact (no level repulsion), leading to a Poisson distribution.

Further reading: [V. Oganesyan and D.A. Huse, Localization of Interacting Fermions at High Temperature, Phys. Rev. B 75, 155111 (2007)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.75.155111)